# Using emacs for ruby development with asdf version manager

Tags: flycheck, ruby, ruby-mode, doom

I have installed a (doom) emacs to start developing with Ruby. So far I have mainly used Sublime Text but because of reasons I want to give emacs a chance.
I tried Spacemacs too but uninstalled this because it was really slow)

A problem I have now is that the minibuffer is constantly showing some errors because it can't access the ruby gem reek which some emacs package uses for code analyzing. I am using the asdf version manager but I have not found a way to tell emacs to use it as well. How can I do this?

Comment: How does asdf work? Does it use executable shims and modified PATH entries like rbenv? Then it might be enough to move its config to `.profile` (on Ubuntu, at least) and relogin.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is now an Emacs lib fixing the issue for you by setting the proper paths:

https://github.com/tabfugnic/asdf.el